# How do I setup .htaccess and mod_rewrite to permanently redirect to a new domain excluding the root index page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to setup .htaccess and mod_rewrite to switch to a new domain.

Currently using (from old domain):

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [domain.com] [R=301,L]

so..
olddomain.com/abc --
domain.com/abc

However, I would like one more feature, but can't seem to get it working. I want every file in the old site to redirect to the new site unless someone visits www.olddomain.com, then i want it to show the olddomain.com/index.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching that with a no-redirect rule before your rewrite?  (I'm not sure whether that regexp needs to be ^$ or ^/$)

```
RewriteRule ^$ - [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ [domain.com] [R=301,L]
```